# How Do I Get A Different Value From A Repeated Function Each Time?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I get 10 of the same result each time for:

```
(repeat 10 (rand 10))
```

for example:

```
=> (2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718 2.54681114871718)
```

I'm assuming it's some kind of memoization, am I right? How do I get a different value each time?

Comment: More answers here https://stackoverflow.com/q/11730978

Comment: You have got two useful answers. Please remember to accept one (here and in the other questions you ask on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 11):

`repeat` returns a sequence containing the given value, so `(rand 10)` is evaluated once as an argument. You can use `repeatedly` which takes a function:

```
(repeatedly 10 #(rand 10))
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that this is due to memoization. `repeat` is just a function, so `(rand 10)` must be evaluated before `repeat` can run. That means that

```
(repeat 10 (rand 10))
```

Needs to evaluate its argument first, and evaluates to (for example):

```
(repeat 10 2.54681114871718)
```

From here, it should be clear why it's returning the same thing over and over again.

To do what you're trying to do, you'd have to use a macro:

```
(defmacro repeatedlyM [n & body]
  `(repeatedly ~n (fn [] ~@body)))

(repeatedlyM 10 (rand 10))

(9.132286678823302
 9.767508843398039
 5.826387907720001
 2.2938644928402283
 8.673658990046192
 8.112592355036686
 2.9539038027898314
 2.721946311854755
 0.53309774963476
 7.258845714766884)
```

This works because the arguments to macros aren't evaluated before the call like they are with plain functions. `(rand 10)` is taken literally, placed inside a function, and run many times instead of once.

Just wrapping the code in a function and using `repeatedly` like the other answer shows though is almost definitely the better solution.