# Why so many 0s in the answer?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

```
(take 100 (iterate rand-int 300))
```

evaluates differently, of course, each time... but usually with a ton of zeros. The result always leads with a 300. For example:

```
(300 93 59 58 25 14 9 4 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

I would have expected 100 random integers between 0 and 300.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: I'm realizing I don't understand iterate... it clearly uses the last iteration to build the next one... so I guess I am wondering how one creates a lazy list of integers between 0 and 300.

Comment: Aaaand... I answer my own question (with the help of another post on here, of course)...  (take 100 (repeatedly #(rand-int 300)))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730978/how-to-create-a-lazy-sequence-of-random-numbers-in-clojure

Comment: Indeed that's the right answer, but it belongs in an Answer, not in a comment on the Question. (answering your own question is perfectly fine on Stack Overflow)

Comment: Thank you... I'll do it correctly the next time around!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See docs for [`iterate`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate):

*Returns a lazy sequence of x, (f x), (f (f x)) etc. f must be free of side-effects*

So, that's the reason your sequence is always starting with `300`.

And why there are so many zeros? When you use `iterate` like this, [`rand-int`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rand-int) takes the previous result and uses it as a new upper limit (exclusive) for a random number. So, your results can look like this:

```
300
=> 300
(rand-int *1)
=> 174
(rand-int *1)
=> 124
(rand-int *1)
=> 29
(rand-int *1)
=> 17
(rand-int *1)
=> 16
(rand-int *1)
=> 7
...
```

You can check yourself that this sequence leads to zero.

If you really want to get 100 random integers between 0 and 300, use [`repeatedly`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeatedly) instead:

`(repeatedly 100 #(rand-int 300))`